# Edit modify files of a share folder by two processors in tow different computers C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two identical process running on two different computers which are accessing a shared folder in a third computer. This share folder have directories.So how to make sure these two processors does not access and start working on the same folder. in other words if one already working on it other skips that directory.

I tried creating a temp file on the directory using File.Create() method 
MSDN state that

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare
>   value of None; no other process or code can access the created file
>   until the original file handle is closed.

So my logic was to skip the directory if the temp file was already there or if a exception was thrown while trying to create it.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work.So my question is

1. Does what MSDN says hold true even if the files are created in a
   shared folder by processors running on different computers or is it
   only valid for local drives
2. A way to actually accomplish what i am trying to do

Comment: Do you keep the files open after creating them, while you process the folder?

Comment: What O/S are your three computers using? This affects the file locking that is used. Anyway, a temp file is useless because of race conditions--think what happens if process A checks for the temp file and finds it is not there, process B then creates the temp file, and then process A accesses the shared folder. Uh-oh!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen temp file is created using File.Create() so i think after file is created it is closed

Comment: No, `File.Create` returns the stream referencing the file. You need to hold on to this and dispose/close it when you're done with it.

Comment: @ShellShock OS for all three is Windows. regarding the race condition if process A checks for the temp file and finds it is not there, process B then creates the temp file, and then process A accesses the shared folder and try to create the temp file, and in that situation i was hoping it will throw a exception but it does not

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen to be precise you are telling me to keep the return value of the File.Create() in a variable until i finish my work on the folder and that would ensure other processors trying to create the same file, will have an exception ?

Comment: If what you said earlier about sharing is true, yes. File.Create a second time while the file is open by another process will throw an exception. You will get an IOException with a HResult of 0x80070020 (the process cannot access the file ...)

Comment: ok thanks will give this a try as well

Comment: If you *don't* hold on to the return value from `File.Create`, then that object (the return value) is eligible for garbage collection, and when that happens the file is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to create a *true* temporary file.

Use this code around your directory processing:

```
public void ProcessDirectory(string path)
{
    using (var lockFile = File.Create(Path.Combine(path, "process.lock"), 256, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
    {
        // process the directory here
    }
}
```

Notice the `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` there. Even if your process terminates abnormally here, the file system will take care to delete the file for you when you close it. In the case of the abnormal termination, the file is closed as part of the process tear down. In the case of a hard power failure, the file might be left behind though.

Note that this method will throw an `IOException` if there is already a lock in there, you need to handle this and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right, perhaps you made a mistake in the implementation?

Here is working code

```
private const string _lockFileName = @"c:\whatever\lock";
private FileStream _lockFile;

public bool Lock()
{
    try
    {
        _lockFile = File.Open(_lockFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        return true;
    }
    catch { } // perhaps a certain exception type?
    return false;
}

public void Unlock()
{
    if(_lockFile != null)
    {
        _lockFile.Close();
        File.Delete(_lockFileName);
        _lockFile = null;
    }
}
```

At start of *using* folder call `Lock()`, work with folder only if it return `true`. At the end call `Unlock()`, it's safe to call even if `Lock()` return `false`.

Comment: Thaks i will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

You can write a lock.conf file in the directory when you start working on it. You then remove the file (releasing the lock) when you are done.

Two considerations:

1. Set a timestamp on the lock file, so that the lock can be ignored after a predetermined time interval (in order to avoid the lock remaining there if the program crashes)
2. Use a function that raises an exception when creating a file if the file is already there, to avoid race conditions.

Comment: do you know any function that will throw a exception while accessing a folder in a different computer (windows OS). i thought File.Create() would do that but it seems it does not unless im missing sumthing